# How do you convert the string "Array{Float64,1}[1,2,3]" to an actual array in Julia?

Tags: type-conversion, julia

I basically want to take a string such as "Array{Float64,1}[1,2,3]" and turn it into an actual array: [1,2,3]

I've already tried the convert function, but julia doesn't like converting things to arrays.

```
convert(Array,x)
```

julia rejects this, saying that it can't convert a string into an array.

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Array
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{Array}, ::DataStructures.CircularBuffer{T}) where T at /Users/benjaminkhoury/.julia/packages/DataStructures/5F6tJ/src/circular_buffer.jl:172
  convert(::Type{T<:Array}, ::AbstractArray) where T<:Array at array.jl:474
  convert(::Type{T<:AbstractArray}, ::T<:AbstractArray) where T<:AbstractArray at abstractarray.jl:14
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is parse a string. You can use the `Meta.parse` function to parse a string into an expression. You can then use `eval` to evaluate the expression:

```
julia> ex = Meta.parse("[1., 2, 3]")
:([1.0, 2, 3])

julia> eval(ex)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
```

Note that I modified your string, since the expression in your string throws an error:

```
julia> Array{Float64,1}[1, 2, 3]
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Array{Float64,1}
```

To quote the docs [(see here)](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Typed-array-initializers-1),

> An array with a specific element type can be constructed using the syntax T[A, B, C, ...]. This will construct a 1-d array with element type T, initialized to contain elements A, B, C, etc.

So `Array{Float64,1}[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` is valid but `Array{Float64,1}[1, 2, 3]` is not.